# A* algorithm in python having trouble with making the final path

Tags: python, algorithm, path-finding

Full now working Code:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1j1BLe4L735nmXWR0Vnj3TeHumzI5x7Ea5yWJSc5j-8w/edit

I tried to code the A* pathfinding algorithm and I got it to expand in the right way using the g and h costs.

It looked really cool, however when I tried finding the final path by using recursion starting on the end node it was wrong in most cases.

I want to know if this is a problem with A* or my code as when I found someone else's code for the algorithm it has the same problem.

I did this using pygame in python.

Here is the relevant part of my code (most of pygame interaction excluded):

```
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
PURPLE = (238, 130, 238)
pygame.init()
width = 1200
hight = 900
startNode = None
endNode = None
SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode((width, hight), pygame.DOUBLEBUF)

class node:

   def __init__(self, pos, h_cost, g_cost, f_cost, Color):
       self.x = pos[0]
       self.y = pos[1]
       self.parent = None
       self.f_cost = f_cost
       self.g_cost = g_cost
       self.h_cost = h_cost
       self.pos = pos
       self.Color = Color

   def TraceBack(self):
       if self.parent != None:
           self.parent.Color = "BLUE"
           self.parent.TraceBack()

   def calG_cost(self, startNode):
       self.g_cost = math.sqrt((self.x - startNode.x) ** 2 + abs(self.y - startNode.y) ** 2)

   def calH_cost(self,endNode):
       self.h_cost = math.sqrt((self.x - endNode.x) ** 2 + abs(self.y - endNode.y) ** 2)

   def calF_cost(self,endNode,startNode):
       self.calG_cost(startNode)
       self.calH_cost(endNode)
       self.f_cost = self.g_cost + self.h_cost

grid = []

def checkIfDone(endNode):
   x = endNode.x
   y = endNode.y
   if grid[x + 1][y].Color == "PURPLE":
       return True

   if grid[x + 1][y + 1].Color == "PURPLE":
       return True
   if grid[x + 1][y - 1].Color == "PURPLE":
       return True
   if  grid[x - 1][y - 1].Color == "PURPLE":
       return True

   if grid[x - 1][y].Color == "PURPLE":
       return True

   if grid[x - 1][y + 1].Color == "PURPLE":
       return True

   if grid[x][y + 1].Color == "PURPLE":
       return True

   if grid[x][y - 1].Color == "PURPLE":
       return True
   return False



def findLowestFCost():
   lowest = math.inf
   lowestNode = None
   for row in grid:
       for node in row:
           if node.Color == "GREEN" and node.f_cost < lowest:
               lowest = node.f_cost
               lowestNode = node

   return lowestNode

def GenerateGrid():
   for x in range(100):
       grid.append([])
       for y in range(100):
           grid[x].append("")

   for y in range(len(grid[0]) ):
       for x in range(len(grid) ):
           grid[x][y] = node((x, y), 0, 0, 0, "")


def checkFound(parent):
   x = parent.x
   y = parent.y
   try:
       if grid[x + 1][y].Color == "RED": return True

       if grid[x + 1][y + 1].Color == "RED": return True

       if grid[x + 1][y - 1].Color == "RED": return True

       if grid[x - 1][y - 1].Color == "RED": return True

       if grid[x - 1][y].Color == "RED": return True

       if grid[x - 1][y + 1].Color == "RED": return True

       if grid[x][y + 1].Color == "RED": return True

       if grid[x][y - 1].Color == "RED": return True

   except:
       pass


def expandParent(parent):
   x = parent.x
   y = parent.y
   if grid[x + 1][y].Color == "" or grid[x + 1][y].Color == "GREEN":
       grid[x + 1][y].Color = "GREEN"

       if grid[x + 1][y].parent == None:
           grid[x + 1][y].parent = parent

       elif parent.f_cost < grid[x + 1][y].parent.f_cost:
           grid[x + 1][y].parent = parent

   if grid[x + 1][y + 1].Color == "" or grid[x + 1][y + 1].Color == "GREEN":
       grid[x + 1][y + 1].Color = "GREEN"

       if grid[x + 1][y + 1].parent == None:
           grid[x + 1][y + 1].parent = parent

       elif parent.f_cost < grid[x + 1][y + 1].parent.f_cost:
           grid[x + 1][y + 1].parent = parent

   if grid[x + 1][y - 1].Color == "" or grid[x + 1][y - 1].Color == "GREEN":
       grid[x + 1][y - 1].Color = "GREEN"

       if grid[x + 1][y - 1].parent == None:
           grid[x + 1][y - 1].parent = parent

       elif parent.f_cost < grid[x + 1][y - 1].parent.f_cost:
           grid[x + 1][y - 1].parent = parent

   if grid[x - 1][y - 1].Color == "" or grid[x - 1][y - 1].Color == "GREEN":
       grid[x - 1][y - 1].Color = "GREEN"

       if grid[x - 1][y - 1].parent == None:
           grid[x - 1][y - 1].parent = parent

       elif parent.f_cost < grid[x - 1][y - 1].parent.f_cost:
           grid[x - 1][y - 1].parent = parent

   if grid[x - 1][y].Color == "" or grid[x - 1][y].Color == "GREEN":
       grid[x - 1][y].Color = "GREEN"

       if grid[x - 1][y].parent == None:
           grid[x - 1][y].parent = parent

       elif parent.f_cost < grid[x - 1][y].parent.f_cost:
           grid[x - 1][y].parent = parent

   if grid[x - 1][y + 1].Color == "" or grid[x - 1][y + 1].Color == "GREEN":
       grid[x - 1][y + 1].Color = "GREEN"

       if grid[x - 1][y + 1].parent == None:
           grid[x - 1][y + 1].parent = parent

       elif parent.f_cost < grid[x - 1][y + 1].parent.f_cost:
           grid[x - 1][y + 1].parent = parent

   if grid[x][y + 1].Color == "" or grid[x][y + 1].Color == "GREEN":
       grid[x][y + 1].Color = "GREEN"

       if grid[x][y + 1].parent == None:
           grid[x][y + 1].parent = parent

       elif parent.f_cost < grid[x][y + 1].parent.f_cost:
           grid[x][y + 1].parent = parent

   if grid[x][y - 1].Color == "" or grid[x][y - 1].Color == "GREEN":
       grid[x][y - 1].Color = "GREEN"

       if grid[x][y - 1].parent == None:
           grid[x][y - 1].parent = parent

       elif parent.f_cost < grid[x][y - 1].parent.f_cost:
           grid[x][y - 1].parent = parent

   parent.Color = "PURPLE"
```

Red is the end node, Blue is the final path, purple is the parent node. I can't see the start node as it gets overwritten. I will fix this at some point:

[image: image of maze]

Worked better here:

[image: image of better maze]

Comment: I don't see any A* algorithm code. Please provide code with which the problem can be reproduced. The A* algorithm guarantees a shortest path when the heuristic function is admissible. As you have not provided either the A* search implementation, nor the heuristic function, we cannot tell you why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Sorry heres a google docs link to the code
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1j1BLe4L735nmXWR0Vnj3TeHumzI5x7Ea5yWJSc5j-8w/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please don't post a link to necessary information for the question. Instead include it in your question (at least the necessary code, not what is not relevant to the question).

Comment: OK, I added it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the main issues is how you calculate the -cost:

```
   def calG_cost(self, startNode):
       self.g_cost = math.sqrt((self.x - startNode.x) ** 2 + abs(self.y - startNode.y) ** 2)
```

This calculates a distance from the starting node to the current node "as the crow flies", but  should reflect the **actual** traversed path. We cannot generally know that from just the start node and the current node. This needs to be accumulated incrementally as nodes are expanded, and the next step is added to the  cost.

Another issue is that `findLowestFCost` is not efficient: it needs to visit every cell in the grid. The A* algorithm is designed for use with a priority queue for this purpose.

`expandParent` has very similar code that gets repeated several times. This can be done in a better way. As you are already using a `Node` class, why not register the neighbors of each node in a `neighbors` attribute. That way you can iterate that `neighbors` collection in a loop.

This is what I did in the following solution. Note that it is text-based, there is no integration with pygame.

```
from heapq import heappop, heappush

DIAGDIST = 2**0.5
# Define meaning of letters
WALL = "#"
START = "y"
END = "r"
NEW = "."
QUEUED = "?"
VISITED = ","
ONPATH = "B"

class Node:
    def __init__(self, pos, *neighbors):
        self.x, self.y = pos
        self.pos = pos
        self.color = NEW
        self.parent = None
        self.f_cost = self.g_cost = float("inf")
        # Define neighbor bi-directional relations 
        self.neighbors = set()
        for neighbor in neighbors:
            if neighbor:
                self.neighbors.add(neighbor)
                neighbor.neighbors.add(self)

    def minDistance(self, other):
        # minimum distance with legal steps when there would be no walls
        dx = abs(self.x - other.x)
        dy = abs(self.y - other.y)
        diag = min(dx, dy)
        straight = max(dx, dy) - diag
        return diag * DIAGDIST + straight

    # Make Node instances comparable; for use by a heap
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return (self.f_cost - other.f_cost or self.x - other.x or self.y - other.y) < 0
    
    def traceBack(self):
        node = self
        while node:
            node.color = ONPATH
            node = node.parent



class Maze:
    def __init__(self, pattern):
        pattern = pattern.replace(" ", "")  # Remove intermediate spaces
        lines = pattern.strip().splitlines()
        row = [None] * len(lines[0])
        self.startNode = self.endNode = None
        self.grid = []
        for x, line in enumerate(lines):
            left = None
            # Create a row of Nodes that are immediately connected to previously created neighbors
            #   Don't create Nodes for Walls.
            row = [left := Node((x, y), left, *row[max(0, y-1):y+2]) if ch != WALL else None 
                   for y, ch in enumerate(line)]
            self.grid.append(row)
            if not self.startNode:
                self.startNode = next((node for node, ch in zip(row, line) if ch == START), None)
            if not self.endNode:
                self.endNode = next((node for node, ch in zip(row, line) if ch == END), None)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return "\n".join([
            " ".join(node.color if node else WALL for node in row)
            for row in self.grid
        ])


    def aStarSearch(self):
        self.startNode.g_cost = 0
        self.startNode.f_cost = self.startNode.minDistance(self.endNode)
        heap = [self.startNode]
        while heap:
            node = heappop(heap)
            if node == self.endNode:  # found target
                node.traceBack()
                # Restore indications of start/end nodes
                self.startNode.color = "y"
                self.endNode.color = "r"
                return
            if node.color != VISITED:
                node.color = VISITED
                for neighbor in node.neighbors:
                    if neighbor.color != VISITED:
                        g_cost = node.g_cost + node.minDistance(neighbor)
                        if g_cost < neighbor.g_cost:
                            h_cost = neighbor.minDistance(self.endNode)
                            neighbor.g_cost = g_cost
                            neighbor.f_cost = g_cost + h_cost
                            neighbor.parent = node
                            neighbor.color = QUEUED
                            heappush(heap, neighbor)
            
            
# Example run (text-based, no pygame)
maze = Maze("""
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . # . . . . . . . . y . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # . . . . .
. . . . # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # . . . . .
. . . . # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # . . . . .
. . . . # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # . . . . .
. . . . # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # . . . . .
. . . . # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # . . . . .
. . . . # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # . . . . .
. . . . # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # . . . . .
. . . . # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # . . . . .
. . . . # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # . . . . .
. . . . # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # . . . . .
. . . . # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # . . . . .
. . . . # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # . . . . .
. . . . # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # . . . . .
. . . . # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # . . . . .
. . . . # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # . . . . .
. . . . # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # . . . . .
. . . . # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # . . . . .
. . . . # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . r . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
""")

maze.aStarSearch()
print(maze)
```

This outputs:

```
. . ? ? , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ? ? . . . . .
. ? ? , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ? ? . . . .
? ? , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ? ? . . .
? , , , B B , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ? ? . .
? , , B # , B , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ? ? .
, , , B # , , B B B B B B y , , , , , , , , , , , , , ? .
, , , B # , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , # , , , ? ?
, , , B # , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , # , , , , ?
, , , B # , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , # , , , , ?
, , , B # , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , # , , , , ?
, , , B # , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , # , , , , ?
, , , B # , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , # , , , , ?
, , , B # , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , # , , , ? ?
, , , B # , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , # , , , ? .
, , , B # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # , , ? ? .
, , , B # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # , , ? . .
, , , B # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # , , ? . .
? , , B # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # , ? ? . .
? , , B # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # , ? . . .
? , , B # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # ? ? . . .
? ? , B # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # . . . . .
. ? , B # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # . . . . .
. ? ? B # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # . . . . .
. . ? B # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # . . . . .
. . ? B # ? ? ? ? ? ? ? . . . . . . . . . . . # . . . . .
. . ? ? B B B B B B B r . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this help a lot i finally got it working! You were right it was the g cost that was wrong. Also as I was fixing it I made a lot of efficiency improvements. All the new code is in the google doc if you're interested. Thanks!

Comment: It is not the right practice to edit a solution link into your question. Instead, if you really want to document the changes you did to make it work, post an answer, and include (not just with a link) the relevant code with an explanation.